# Google Maps marker doesn't display å, ä, ö

Tags: javascript, google-maps, razor, google-maps-api-3

I place several markers on a Google Map (v3) with the the title attribute set to swedish names. The values are outputted from C# and the source is a XML-file that has utf-8 as charset. When outputting the character ö I get `&amp;#246;`.

I call the google maps js as follows -> `https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&language=sv. 
I have tried to do JSON.Encode(value) but it doesn't work.

I set the markers like this ->

```
var position = new google.maps.LatLng(value, value);
            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: position,
                map: map,
                url: value,
                title: 'value from C#'
            });
            marker.setIcon(icon);
```

What do I need to do to make Google output å as å, ä as ä and so on?
Thanks for the help!

EDIT:

When doing `@(new HtmlString(value))`, it now works.

Comment: What is the exact output of the C# program? It may be that it's already autoformatted there...

Comment: Yeah, seems like that was the problem, did @(new HtmlString(value)) and it works now. Thanks!

Comment: can you show your razor template?

Comment: This might be relevant: [Guide to using special characters in HTML: Tooltips and other special texts](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/html/characters.html#tooltips)